# how to upgrade iPad 1 to iOS 6

Tags: ipad

I am having trouble with installing apps from App Store,  it pops up "this app requires iOS 6.0 and later".. I've been trying to upgrade the iPad to iOS 6.0 and it is saying iOS 5.01.is the latest version..  What to do?

Comment: Your iPad is too old to be updated, so you have to buy a newer iPad or live without the app.

Answer (score 8):

The latest supported version for the [1st generation iPad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPad_(1st_generation)) is iOS 5.1.1. That means it's **not possible** to upgrade it to iOS 6 (or higher). You'll have to buy another one. Even if it would run iOS 6, it would be terribly slow. Modern apps are developed with way more memory and CPU power in mind.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Apple decided to leave the 1st generation iPad on iOS 5.1.1, yet update the iPod touch 4th generation, which shares specs with the iPad, to iOS 6. But just because you're not able to normally, doesn't mean it isn't possible. [iOS 7 was ported over to the 4th gen iPod touch](https://albyvar.github.io/ipodtouchhax/) despite being left on iOS 6.1.6, so you shouldn't give up yet.